# Sending android app notification to facebook using facebook API Notification

Tags: android, facebook, notifications

Hi I want to send notifications from android app to facebook. To send facebook notification i got this link : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications/  But i am not sure how to use this link in android to send notification.

Please can any body guide me for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't send notifications from an Android app. Tried to POST using the link you provided and got the following error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#200) Only web canvas apps can send app notifications","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}
```

Maybe you could use this one:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/send-requests/

Answer (score 0):

We're not allowed to send notifications from Android app using the notifications API, nor sending App Requests from non game app using Requests APIs. I'm interested too to know how can we notify the user from non-game-android app.